# Can't find Git or Cordova on your path (Windows/Netbeans), Can't find GitHub under AppData/Local, FIX 2015

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, netbeans

**Error:** NetBeans cannot find git or cordova on your path.

**When** trying to create a new Cordova Application in Netbeans.

**How to fix? > THE ANSWER CAN BE FOUND BELOW :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone wants to know how to get Cordova working in Netbeans anno 2015/2016 here is the fix:

I have installed:

- Git version: 2.5.1 for Windows 64 bit
- Cordova version: 4.3.1 for Windows 64 bit
- Node.js version: 0.12.0 for Windows 64 bit
- Netbeans version: 8.0.2 x86

In Netbeans when I start a new project and select HTML5>Cordova Application then I will get this **error:NetBeans cannot find git or cordova on your path.**

After some searching on the good old internet, I found some pieces of information hither and thither which was correct but which didn't solve my problem. The reason for this was that it was old or slightly different than my problem. So I did the following to fix this problem:

I checked where my Cordova/npm files where and I happily found them in: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

Next I had to find my Git.exe which FOR ME is located in: C:\Program Files\Git\bin (FOR SOME PEOPLE IT CAN BE FOUND IN: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_)

Now I found out that Netbeans is using the windows PATH VARIABLES to locate git and cordova. For those who don't where to find or set the system Path Variables this website will help you find or set it: https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

I use windows 7 so I did this to change my path variables:"

-Select Computer from the Start menu

-Choose System Properties from the context menu

-Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab

-Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.

-In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.

SO edit path and then you see like C:/apath;C:/asdas; < **enter here your git path**;<**enter here your cordova path** and save it by clicking the OK button.

Restart Netbeans and now it has to work.

:)

Answer (score 1):

For those getting here and the solution from @bboni did not work - as it did for me:

Make sure everything is installed correctly by opening a command prompt (open start-menu and type `cmd`).
Type the following commands `git --version`, `cordova -v` and `node -v`.

For me it looked like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\JohnDoe>git --version
git version 2.8.4.windows.1

C:\Users\JohnDoe>cordova -v
6.2.0

C:\Users\JohnDoe>node -v
v4.4.5
```

That makes sure everything is installed correctly. If one or more commands result in an error, then it's either not installed or not added to `PATH` as described by @bboni.

Now open your Netbeans and go to **Tools** → **Options** → **HTML/JS** → **Mobile Platforms** and check if you can see somethink like `Installed Cordova version: 6.2.0`. This is to make sure Netbeans is basically able to detect Cordova.

At that point all the tutorials I found online ended. I came up with the idea to check if Netbeans' own Terminal would be able to execute the command above as well: **Tools** → **Open in Terminal**
I got an error telling me I'd need *[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)* to use the Terminal. So I installed it, restarted Netbeans, opened the Terminal, checked the commands above and they worked.

I checked *Configure Cordova* again - the error was gone and I could finally ran my app directly from Netbeans as I wanted to.   ***`:)`***